# Web API .NET 6: Catching exceptions early and replacing them with different ones

Tags: exception, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following question:

Let's say I have a standard WebAPI project under ASP.NET Core 6. The project references a class library and the API controllers make calls to services in that library. Naturally, when some unexpected error occurs, a specific exception is thrown that lives in the class library.

I wonder if the following is somehow possible in a Web API project: Intercept class library exceptions early (done by the API), and for each type re-throw a corresponding exception that lives in the API. The latter exception is what should reach my controller action method to be handled in a try-catch block. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Pls share enough coed for your scenario to explain more detailed.

Comment: I honestly do not think it is relevant as the problem is very well defined. Instead of having an initial exception (that is defined in a class library that I use) reach the controller, I would like to intercept it and throw a different exception, one implemented in the API project.